# Possible Trees using translation scheme for post fix notation of 7-2+3

Tags: tree, compiler-construction, postfix-notation

I was asked to convert 7-2+3 into post fix notation while no operator precedence or left to right or right to left was mentioned in the question and then I had to make tree using translation scheme of the post fix notion ed result.

I found it ambiguous because 7-2+3 may give 2 possible results 8 and 2 so I wrote two post fix notations 72-3+ & 723+- and made two possible trees using translation scheme.

I want to confirm either I was Correct or Not.

Answer (score 1):

If you apply [Shunting-yard algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shunting-yard_algorithm) to `7-2+3` the output is `72-3+`

**Note:** `+` and `-` are `left associative` and have the `same precedence` unless otherwise indicated

Answer (score 0):

Postfix notation is also called as '`suffix notation'` and `'reverse polish'`.  linear representation of a syntax tree. In the postfix notation, any expression can be written **unambiguously without parentheses**.

in first part of your question for postfix notation of any infix expression:
     **

> Scan the infix expression from left to right.

**
so following the algorithm this one is correct `72-3+` and for this you have to make tree or what ever there is mentioned..
for further details regarding postfix rules check it out

https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/stack-set-2-infix-to-postfix/

leh me know if you find it useful